# What does the statement "...you can express it as a sum over basis vectors..." mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, hilbert-spaces

> Generally when you have a vector $\lvert\psi\rangle$, you can express it as a sum
>   over $N$ basis vectors $\lvert\phi_i\rangle$ where $N$ is the dimension of the
>   Hilbert space. $i$ is the the integer that labels the basis vectors.

Could someone explain me what the above statement means **with an example**? (I know what basis vectors are and what Hilbert space is)

Comment: Write $v=|\psi>$ and $v_i=|\phi_i$. Then $v=\sum_{i=1}^N\lambda_iv_i$ for scalars $\lambda_i$, since the $v_i$ are a basis, hence a generating system.

Comment: What does ["basis"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)) mean? Linear independent and generating (spanning).

Comment: This is called a "linear combination".  So it looks like a linear algebra course should be a prerequisite for that book/course/lecture/video or whatever it is quoted there.

Comment: Which word in the sentence do you not understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give a simple example, consider the vector space $(\Bbb R\times \Bbb R, +, \cdot)$ with the usual entry wise sum and scalar multiplication.

We can write any vector $\psi$, say $(45,68)$ as a sum of basis vectors $\phi_1=(1,0), \phi_2=(3,4)$, namely, $\psi=-6 \cdot\phi_1 +17\cdot \phi_2$.

The same applies to any kind of object in a vector space, including functions.